# How to construct a Poisson process not based on Lebesgue measure?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

It is clear to me that I can build a suitable underlying probability space for a [homogeneous Poisson point process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Homogeneous_Poisson_point_process).

It is enough to have a pobability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ with on it iid random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots$ having exponential distribution.

So I could do already with $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ applied with product measure.

Then $N_t$ can be defined as the cardinality of the set $\{n\mid S_n\leq t\}$ where $S_n:=X_1+\dots+X_n$.

If $A$ is a measurable subset of $[0,\infty)$ then I can define random variable $\hat A$ as the (random) cardinality of $\{n\mid S_n\in A\}$ and then $\hat A$ has Poisson-distribution with a (multiple of) $\lambda(A)$ as parameter, where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. In that sense it can be called a Poisson process **on base of the Lebesgue measure**.

Now my question:

> How to build up a probability space allowing me to construct a Poisson process **based on an arbitrary chosen measure** $\nu$ on $[0,\infty)$ with the property that $\nu([0,t])<\infty$ for each $t$?

So this means that for a measurable $A\subseteq[0,\infty)$ the random cardinality of $\{n\mid S_n\in A\}$ has Poisson-distribution with parameter $\nu(A)$. Further if two such sets $A,B$ are disjoint then $\{n\mid S_n\in A\}$ and $\{n\mid S_n\in B\}$ must be independent (as is also the case described above).

Comment: Have you seen the discussion of inhomogeneous Poisson point processes on Wikipedia?

Comment: @fourierwho Now I have. Thank you for attending me. Promising is the sentence: "A feature of the one-dimension setting, is that an inhomogeneous Poisson process can be transformed into a homogeneous by a monotone transformation or mapping, which is achieved with the inverse of $\Lambda$". That seems to say that the existence of a homogeneous Poisson process can be used to construct a inhomogeneous Poisson process. So underlying space $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ would also be enough for that. I am not sure though, and do not see yet how to achieve this.

Comment: You might be interested in this article: http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/publ/92/n086p063.pdf

Comment: @saz Thank you. I will take a look there.